# create trigger on table copy the data to other table with different columns

Tags: mysql, postgresql, function, triggers

Hi i have two tables below

```
Table1

id name comment

Table2

id name comment
```

i want to get like below

if i `insert into Table1(1,'a','warning'')`

Table2 will update `()1,'a','warning came')`

and `insert into Table1(1,'a','critical'')`

Table2 wil update `()1,'a','criticalcame')`

I am trying with below but am unable to solve problem

trigger

```
DELIMITER //

create trigger TableTrigger after insert on Table1
    for each row
        case when  Table1.comment=warning then 
     insert into Table2(id, name,comment) values (new.id, new.name,'warning came');
     end case;
```

please help regarding this thanks advance

Comment: Why do you have both postgresql and mysql tagged? Which one are you using?

Comment: `Table1.comment=warning`  The quotes are missing for `'warning'` ..?